# Dictionary within dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm seeking to make a function `addproperty(property_str, property_dict, old_dict = None)` where I you need as arguments a string, one dictionary and one optional dictionary.
The function needs to return a new dictionary where the corresponding values are added to the optional dictionary.

For instance. If I enter:

```
capitals_dict = {'USA': 'Washington', 'Russia': 'Moscow', 'Japan': 'Tokyo'}
```

The function `addproperty('capital', capitals_dict)` needs to return the following dictionary

```
{'USA': {'capital': 'Washington'}, 'Russia': {'capital': 'Moscow'}, 'Japan': {'capital': 'Tokyo'}}
```

I also need to be able to expand such dictionary to add new details to those countries when I enter that dictionary in the optional parameter.

For instance:

```
old_dict = {'USA': {'capital': 'Washington'}, 'Russia': {'capital': 'Moscow'}, 'Japan': 'capital': 'Tokyo'}}
demonym_dict = {'USA': 'American', 'Russia': 'Russian', 'Japan': 'Japanese'}
```

Then `addproperty('demonym', demonym_dict, old_dict)` needs to return:

```
{'USA': {'capital': 'Washington', 'demonym': 'American'}, 'Russia': {'capital': 'Moscow', 'demonym': 'Russian'}, 'Japan': {'capital': 'Tokyo', 'demonym': 'Japanese'}}
```

How should I start here?

Comment: Is there a reason these two very different operations have to be the same function with an optional parameter?

Comment: Educational reason, nothing else.

Answer (score 5):

```
def addproperty(property_str, property_dict, old_dict=None):
    result = old_dict if old_dict is not None else {}
    for k, v in property_dict.items():
        result.setdefault(k, {})[property_str] = v
    return result
```

For example:

```
>>> capitals_dict = {'USA': 'Washington', 'Russia': 'Moscow', 'Japan': 'Tokyo'}
>>> result = addproperty('capital', capitals_dict)
>>> result
{'Japan': {'capital': 'Tokyo'}, 'Russia': {'capital': 'Moscow'}, 'USA': {'capital': 'Washington'}}
>>> demonym_dict = {'USA': 'American', 'Russia': 'Russian', 'Japan': 'Japanese'}
>>> addproperty('demonym', demonym_dict, result)
{'Japan': {'demonym': 'Japanese', 'capital': 'Tokyo'}, 'Russia': {'demonym': 'Russian', 'capital': 'Moscow'}, 'USA': {'demonym': 'American', 'capital': 'Washington'}}
```

Note that this will modify `old_dict` if it is provided.  If this is a problem import the copy module and replace the first line in the function with the following:

```
result = copy.deepcopy(old_dict) if old_dict is not None else {}
```

Comment: Many many thanks. I also know some people would use the `zip` function here. Your method even seem shorter. I wonder which would be most 'Pythonic'.

Comment: Well, the fact it modifies the old_dict is no issue here. Whenever it's 'updated', that old_dict is of no use. Exactly what I needed. I will keep in mind the `copy` module for the future, though. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: You should modify your question to clarify because you do say, "The function needs to return a **new** dictionary." How would one use `zip()` here? It certainly doesn't seem like a natural use of zip. Maybe you should write an answer that shows us.

Answer (score 2):

My crazy one-line solution :)

```
def addproperty(property_str, property_dict, old_dict = None):
    return {k: (lambda k, v: old_dict[k] if old_dict != None else { property_str: v})(k,v) for k, v in property_dict.items()}
```

Returns new dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def add_property(item,dic,new_dic=None):
    if not new_dic:
        for k,v in dic.items():
            dic[k]={item:v}
    else:        
        for k,v in dic.items():
            dic[k].update({item:new_dic[k]})
   .....:             

In [124]: capitals_dict = {'USA': 'Washington', 'Russia': 'Moscow', 'Japan': 'Tokyo'}

In [125]: add_property("Capital", capitals_dict)

In [126]: add_property("demonym",capitals_dict,demonym_dict)

In [128]: capitals_dict
Out[128]: 
{'Japan': {'Capital': 'Tokyo', 'demonym': 'Japanese'},
 'Russia': {'Capital': 'Moscow', 'demonym': 'Russian'},
 'USA': {'Capital': 'Washington', 'demonym': 'American'}}
```